# How to add timezone offset to string without changing the time?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a time string like this `2021-12-29T01:30:00.105Z`. I want to add offset for a timezone without changing the date and time. So it should look like this after conversion - `2021-12-29T01:30:00+08:00` for "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" timezone.

So `2021-12-29T01:30:00.105Z` -> `2021-12-29T01:30:00+08:00`

I cannot do a string replace since the timezone will be dynamic and does not always has to be "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur".

I am using moment and moment-timezone libraries and have tried different ways to get the required result but none seems to work.

Please help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Otherwise people are likely to give you the same thing again. You do realize that those strings do not represent same time since first is UTC?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I am aware they will represent different time, thanks.

Comment: Suggest you be a lot more specific about your use case and the higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by 'timezone will be dynamic' either, need to elaborate on that

Comment: @skara9 for a record in a database i have a time like `2021-12-29T01:30:00.105Z` and a timezone like `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur`. But the timezone could be different for different records so I cannot do a string replace with  `+08:00`

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/: "*On passing a second parameter as `true`, only the timezone (and offset) is updated, keeping the local time same.*"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IANA name for the timezone and you want to change the timezone of a date in `+XX:XX` format without modifying the time, you can calculate the offset and replace it in the string:

```js
const timeString = '2021-12-29T01:30:00.105Z';
const timezone = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur';

const offset = Intl.DateTimeFormat([], {timeZone: timezone, timeZoneName: 'longOffset'}).formatToParts().find(o => o.type === 'timeZoneName').value.match(/\+.*$/)[0];
const newTimeString = timeString.replace(/\..+Z$/, offset);

console.log(timeString);
console.log(newTimeString);
```